# Chromecast after upgrade - devices no longer detectible

Tags: android, chromecast

I am creating a Chromecast sender app. Previously a built-in Chromecast version was 1.36.xxx and the Android sender app was able to detect the Chromecast device using the following code:

```
castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(applicationContext);
router = MediaRouter.getInstance(applicationContext);
```

However, I've just upgraded my built-in Chromecast to version 1.42.xxx (which according to this: https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/7124014?hl=en-GB is 2nd generation Chromecast) and after this upgrade the Chromecast device is no longer detectible in my Android sender app.

Has anyone encountered this before? Could there be an issue with the Chromecast receiver app not being compatible with 2nd generation devices?

Note: I am using an unpublished receiver app - however, my Chromecast device has been registered with the serial number. Also, this is using the Built-in Chromecast app for AndroidTVs.

We are using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:17.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android TV, I don't think you can use the firmware for the generation 2 chromecast device. According to https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/7124014?hl=en the latest version for Android TV is:

> Cast for Android TV — Firmware version  1.36154871